# AR.JS Web Desktop Performance Low Frame-rate

Tags: javascript, html, augmented-reality, frame-rate, ar.js

Currently working on an augmented reality experience using ar.js. Mobile browsers are getting 60FPS consistently. Desktop browsers are getting 20-30FPS. Anyone have any experience or solutions with this issue?